# AJAX POST call to a controller is passing NULL

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

### Call from View

```js
$.ajax({
    url: _urls.saveNoteDetailsUrl,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(inputModel),
    success: function (response) {
       window.location.assign(_urls.ReturnToHomePageUrl);
    }
```

### Controller

1. ### Approach 1

   ```cs
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult SaveNote(PNoteRequest model)
   ```
2. ### Approach 2

   ```cs
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult SaveNote([FromBody] PNoteRequest model)
   ```

Approach1 gets a model but the values are all null
Approach2 passes a NULL for the model itself.

The same end point is called from another View that gives the same error if I use approach1 but it works fine if I use Approach2. The inputModel structure is slightly different there are some extra keyvalue pairs present in the nonworking call compared to the working call. I have ensured that all the Keys are present in the ViewModel.

If I do the following changes then the calls from both the Views do work

1. Pass the `inputModel` as is discarding the `JSON.Stringify` method.
2. Remove the `contentType` parameter in the AJAX call
3. Remove the `[FromBody]` tag from the controller method

but the data is passed around as urlencoded and that gives me another issue when the inputModel becomes huge. So I need to pass the data in JSON format and not urlencoded.

How do I fix?

---

Thanks for your replies. I think I did not explain the issue properly. There are 2 views making an AJAX POST call to the same end point. Everything works fine if the object passed around is not huge. If the object is huge then it passes a NULL for the model to the CONTROLLER. To fix the above issue I made the following changes 1) Added [FromBody] to the CONTROLLER 2) Added contentType parameter and JSON.Stringify() to the AJAX call in the VIEWS. Now call from one of the VIEW works but the other does not. The other call passes a NULL for the model to the CONTROLLER

---

I am trying to provide as much info as possible. The code in the 2 views are huge, concatenating the values from the screen to construct the inputModel. I have verified multiple times, the difference in the AJAX calls is in NoteInfo key only.

Here is the PNoteRequest class file. There are about 30 other properties in the PNoteRequest class.

```
public class PNoteRequest
{
  public int RequestId { get; set; }
  public NoteInfo NoteInfo { get; set; }
  public string RequestText { get; set; }
  public string RecordNo { get; set; }
}
```

There are about 20 other properties in NoteInfo class.

```
public class NoteInfo
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public bool? IsSAR { get; set; }
  public int MemoOverRideRecordNumber { get; set; }
  public bool IsToReplaceSAR { get; set; }
  public int? Region { get; set; }
  public string QISNo { get; set; }
  public string RevisionComments { get; set; }  
}
```

The difference between the calls from the 2 views are in the NotInfo properties

Request Payload for call that works

```
{"RequestId":4062,
 "NoteInfo":{"Title":"Save Note Check For Small JSON Object.",
            "Description":"AJAX call for save NOTE and save SAR.",
            "IsSAR":false}
}
```

Request Payload for call that pauses NULL

```
{"RequestId":0,
 "NoteInfo":{"Title":"Save Note Check For Small JSON Object.",
            "Description":"AJAX call for save NOTE and save SAR.",
            "IsToReplaceSAR":false,
            "MemoOverRideRecordNumber":"",
            "RevisionComments":"",
            "Region":"",
            "QISNo":""}
}
```

Comment: If you remove `JSON.stringify` and keep everything else (i.e., do #1 and only #1 from your list) with Approach2, it should not URL encode anything.

Comment: Please post the model. I bet this is a case issue.

Comment: In other to help  you, you have to show us PNoteRequest class and inputmodel json. How we can help without nothing what you are sending and what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second json doesnt pass validation, this is why it return null, for example this properties are not valid

```
 "MemoOverRideRecordNumber":"",
 "Region":"",
```

the first is  int,   the second is int? type , so it should be

```
"MemoOverRideRecordNumber":0,
"Region":null,
```

in order to convert them you need to change a properties type to string or write a custom json converter

Comment: Thanks. That was it, I am surprised that this did not cause an error when the model was passed around without JSONIFY.